# Nagios: How to use crit= and warn= in CheckEventlog

Tags: nagios, nsclient++

I am using CheckEventLog of NSClient++0.4.1 to do a real-time monitoring.

And according to official documentation, there were `warn` and `crit` options.

```
warn

  Expression which raises a warning status.

  Syntax: warn=ARGUMENT

  Sample:

    check_eventlog ... warn=ARGUMENT ...

crit

  Expression which raises a critical status.

  Syntax: crit=ARGUMENT

  Sample:

    check_eventlog ... crit=ARGUMENT ...
```

But it didn't explain how to use the options.

What does `ARGUMENT` mean?

Can I use it like the `filter` option, for example: `crit=type = warning AND source = 'System'`?

Need some help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation you refer (I am guessing http://docs.nsclient.org) to is for 0.4.2.
ANd yes in 0.4.2 you can use them exactly like filter so you could do:

```
check_eventlog "warn=id=23 and source = 'foo'"
```

In 0.4.1 warn/crit only matches number of hits. 0.4.2 uses check_eventlog where as the old version has CheckEventLog. So whenever you use check_eventlog you can use the "new way"
The following shows the difference.

```
# 0.3.9 and later (still valid in 0.4.2 but not the best way)
CheckEventLog warn=>5
# 0.4.2 and later
check_eventlog "warn=count>5"
```

If you ask me anything except crit=>0 does not really make sense in versions previous to 0.4.2 and instead you have to use multiple checks.